# Find if an element with a specific property value is found in a list

Tags: list, kotlin, find, contains

I'm trying to find a value in a list of objects in kotlin, using for it "filter", but I need to return true or false if the value is found, but filter returns me a list of object in the case of match.

```
t.filter { it.retailerId == value }
```

¿How I can return a boolean when I find this value in the list of objects?

Comment: You can use `t.any { it.retailerId == value }`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you need that the element is exactly one:

```
t.filter { it.retailerId == value }.size == 1
```

if not:

```
t.any { it.retailerId == value }
```

With foldRight and a break when you found it:

```
t.foldRight(false) {val, res ->
                if(it.retailerId == value) {
                    return@foldRight true
                } else {
                    res
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 14):

In alternative to `firstOrNull` you can also use `any` with the same predicate:

```
val found = t.any { it.retailerId == value }
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`firstOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/first-or-null.html) with the specific predicate:

```
val found = t.firstOrNull { it.retailerId == value } != null
```

If `firstOrNull()` does not return `null` this means that the value is found.

Comment: Nice too, but I'm searching for a way to return a boolean, if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: `t.firstOrNull { it.retailerId == value } != null` returns a Boolean. If you mean a method that directly returns a Boolean then look at `any()`.

Comment: Note that if the list is nullable and predicate may return `true` on a `null` reference, it becomes ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

For single element

```
list.first { it.type == 2 (eg: conditions) } 
or
list.firstOrNull { it.type == 2 (eg: conditions) }
```

For list of elements

```
list.filter { it.type == 2 (eg: conditions) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has this nice extension function which u can use

```
if (none { it.isSelected == true }) {
                first().isSelected = true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`tab.none { it.property == value}`

This expression return true, if the value is not found